# Configuring pass-through Windows Auth - MVC 4 / IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis, windows-authentication

I just changed companies and I am building my first app here.  MVC intranet app at work.  I have the web config set as I usually for pass through windows auth but I am getting pop up login window when I run the app from VS2013.  Is there some external settings that I need to check?  Something with the IIS settings on my box?  Some network setting I should look into?

Edit - My setup is:
Webconfig:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
 <authorization>
   <deny users="?" />
 </authorization>
```

Project properties:

```
Windows Auth enabled
Anonymous disabled.
```

IIS Express:

```
Windows auth enabled
Basic Auth disabled.
```

Edit - I normally develop in Chrome, which is where I am having the problem.  I just tried in IE and the app starts up fine, with no login window.  So the problem is only happening in chrome.  Thoughts?

Edit - I was finally able to have the netwrok admin add Localhost to the trusted sites, no help.  Still looking for ideas.

Comment: What changes did you make to your web.config?  Did you simply set the authentication mode?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark, but try adding localhost to "Local Intranet" sites to your trusted sites in internet options (IE). Maybe dabble with "Autodetect local intranet sites". I realize your problem is in Chrome.

I am unsure why it wouldn't be trusted (Auto NTLM prompts for credentials from untrusted sites). The setting is in the Security tab; if you click Custom Level at the very bottom you can see the selection -- it should be auto logon to intranet sites; and sites without a tld domain should be automatically detected as local intranet. Or this thought might lead you to a solution, maybe.

Comment: My local network admin has finally added 'LocalHost' to the trusted sites, but this made no difference, I still get asked for credentials in Chrome.  Any other ideas?